# WPF MEF Prism dependency discovery within modules

Tags: wpf, prism, mef

I have a WPF Prism app with a main project containing the shell and basic bootstrapping, then I have two modules for different functionality. I also have a separate Data Access project which exports the IDataRepository and DataContext objects to the MEF container. I have added the data project to my assembly catalog in the main bootsrapper and I can see it discovers those two data types.

My problem is that when in Module A, A view model tries to load an IDataRepository object through constructor injection, it throws an error. If I try the constructor injection in my main project it works fine, so it is only within the Module A that I cannot load this shared dependency.

If I export interface types within Module A, it recognises those. So it seems within a module, I can only resolve dependencies that were exported within the module, it doesn't pick up any interface types from outside the module. Is there something basic I am doing wrong?

Comment: What kind of Exception are you facing? It would be helpful if you could tell us the error message as it seems that everything you described is correct.

Comment: I should have noted down the exception actually, I managed to fix it in the end by importing the type IDataRepository in the IModule class for the module. As long as it's imported in the IModule class, it's available throughout the rest of the module it seems.